# new command is expanding as blank

Tags: macros, expansion, csvsimple

So I'm trying to import a large list of values that are used throughout my report. However when i do this the results are always blank...

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
%
\csvloop{file={keyval.csv}, head to column names, command=%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname \Key
    \endcsname{\Value}
}
%
\begin{document}
During test number TR-\testNumber{} a \vehicle{} was subject to etc.... 
\end{document}
```

and in the folder is the csv file; keyval.csv;

```
Key, Value
testNumber, 001
vehicle, Volkswagen Beetle
```

basically the result is;

During test number TR a was subject to etc...

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you've defined `\testNumber` here to expand to `\Value`, whereas you want it to expand to what `\Value` was when you 
created it. That needs an `\edef`, or better a `\protected@edef`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Key, Value
testNumber, 001
vehicle, Volkswagen Beetle
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\makeatletter
\csvloop{file={\jobname.csv}, head to column names, command=%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname \Key
    \endcsname{\Value}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
During test number TR-\testNumber{} a \vehicle{} was subject to etc.... 
\end{document}
```

The reason for this is that TeX is a macro expansion language. With

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname \Key
\endcsname{\Value}
```

the `\Key` is expanded (by `\csname`) to give you `\testNumber` but the `\Value` is not. On the other hand, `\edef` forces expansion of the replacement text. The `\protectd@edef` version is safe with content that is made up of LaTeX macros, for example if you have any formatting in the CSV file.

Comment: Works perfectly! it is interesting that the returned value was blank, rather than an error in the log.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting to expand `\Value`, which can be easily done by adding a couple of `\expandafter` tokens. I prefer to separate things and hide the complicated code into a macro rather than the argument to `\csvloop`.

The idea is of exploiting the fact that `\csname` does full expansion, so an `\expandafter` in front of `\endcsname` is expanded, which triggers the expansion of the next one, which finally expands (once) `\Value`. Otherwise you'd essentially obtain `\newcommand\testNumber{\Value}`, so the *current* meaning of `\Value` would be used, not the one at definition time.

However, there's a small complication: `\Value` must be expanded *twice*, because the first level expansion of `\Value` is `\csvcolii` (an internal representation of the cell content). Not a problem: use a triple `\expandafter` sequence.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Key, Value
testNumber, 001
vehicle, Volkswagen Beetle
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\definekeytovalue}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand
    \csname#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}%
}

\csvloop{
  file={\jobname.csv},
  head to column names,
  command=\definekeytovalue{\Key}{\Value}
}

\begin{document}

During test number TR-\testNumber{} a \vehicle{} was subject to etc....

\end{document}
```

[image]